# how to read local text file using angular js1

Tags: angularjs

I have to read local text file which contains some data I need to extract some specific data from it but when I am using 
it is reading and displaying whole file in HTML.

CODE:

```
<div ng-include="'filedta.txt'">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Edo, file is on the client not on server.

Comment: Files on the client are accessed with `<input type='file' />`. For more information, see [MDN Developer Reference - Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by local? On the client, or on the server?
Anyway, since the code you posted has access to the file, I guess it's on the server, so you can use

```
$http.get('filedta.txt').then(function(data) {
  //use the file data here
});
```

Comment: The file is on clinet

Comment: If it's in the client folder of your app, the above code will work, if that folder is exposed as a static resource.